# Spring MVC: how to make site language selection remembered across browsers?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for a website with two languages: English and Chinese.

I have the following in the Spring context

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"> 
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

I am able to see the language of the website changes if I select another language through a dropdown in the HTML interface.

Suppose I am viewing the website when its language is Chinese. I close the browser. Then I open the browser again and I enter the url of the website without the lang parameter in the URL.

Here is the issue: Chrome is able to remember what the language was when the browser was closed and use that language when the new browser window is opened. This is the behavior I want to have. However, Firefox does not. When I open it and enter the site url, it always shows the site in the site's default language (English in this case).

How can I make the Firefox (or other browsers) open the site with the language used when it was closed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add a SessionLocaleResolver.

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

If you do not add this then I'm pretty sure the default behavior is that the AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver will be used, which resolves the locale by checking the accept-language header in the HTTP request. This means your browser will make the determination, use your language preferences and send the language choice in the accept header.

If your application is stateless then you may need to use the [CookieLocaleResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html) instead.

Comment: Brian,  I did what you mentioned already, but the solution is different.

Answer (score 1):

After research, I found out the solution. I need to set locale resolver this way:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="clientLang" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="31556926" />
</bean>
```

Put it another, I need to give it life to persistent for some time by setting a value to cookieMaxAge. I tested it out in Firefox and Safari, it worked well. This thread has the credit:

[When I used CookieLocaleResolver, I can set invalid cookie to crash spring web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073953/when-i-used-cookielocaleresolver-i-can-set-invalid-cookie-to-crash-spring-web-a)

Cheers!